# Get types of classes for templates

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, type-deduction, template-argument-deduction

I have template function as this:

```
template<class RandomAccessIterator, class T, class Func>
T reduce(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, const T& initial_value, Func func) {
    // Some code;
    return cur_value;
}
```

I can't start thread by:

```
std::thread t1(reduce, iterator1, iterator2, 0, sum)
```

Because `reduce` function isn't created due to `template` behavior.
I must write manually all types of defined in `template`. Like:

```
std::thread t1(reduce<SomeIterator, SomeNumber, SomeFunc>, iterator1, iterator2, 0, sum)
```

If I have another types I should write:

```
std::thread t1(reduce<AnotherIterator, AnotherNumber, Func>, iterator1, iterator2, 0, sum)
```

How can I automate this process? Is there a method to calculate types of classes like:

```
std::thread t1(reduce<typeof(X), typeof(Y), typeof(Z)>, iterator1, iterator2, 0, sum)
```

Comment: maybe [`declytype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)?

Comment: btw "I can't start thread by:" thats because `reduce` is not a function, it is just a template

Comment: where do you call `std::thread t1(...)` if this isnt inside a template, writing `declytype(someObject)` isnt much shorter than just typing `typeOfObject`. On the other hand, if it is inside a template, then maybe you know already the types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a lambda.

```
std::thread t1([=](){reduce(iterator1, iterator2, 0, sum));
```

Magic!

Answer (score 6):

You can write a helper function template to take advantage of [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction):

```
template<class RandomAccessIterator, class T, class Func>
std::thread reduce_helper(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, const T& initial_value, Func func) {
    return std::thread(reduce<RandomAccessIterator, T, Func>, first, last, initial_value, func);
}
```

then use it as:

```
std::thread t1 = reduce_helper(iterator1, iterator2, 0, sum);
```